# Gradient at width 100% covering over and bound to an image with width of 50% and max-height of 90%

Tags: html, css, image, gradient, linear-gradients

I'm terrible at HTML/CSS, and I'm utterly stumped by this.

Image requirements:

- Positioned in the bottom right corner

  - Slight spacing to right (`right: 2%;`, or similar)
  - Bottom of image flush to bottom of window
- Max-height of 95% of window
- Max-width of 50% of window

In other words, the image MUST NOT exceed half the width of any window or over 95% of the height of the window. Extra space above or to the sides are fine.

Gradient requirements:

- Transparent from top to blue bottom (`background: linear-gradient( to bottom, transparent 0, blue 100%);`)
- Placed over the image (`z-index: 1;`)
- Width of 100% of window at all times
- **Height MATCHES the image to cover it by height exactly (i.e. The gradient must cover**

  - In other words, the gradient must color the image the same shade at each height evenly across ALL screen proportions and sizes

EDIT: Another requirement, for clarification:

- No overflowing or scrolling. Image, divs, and gradient must be completely showing on the screen. The image is never partially hidden, and no scroll bars should appear.

**Examples (but...):**

I don't know why jsfiddle and codepen aren't positioning correctly below. At least the positioning works fine in my local code:
This is the best I could do for now:

https://jsfiddle.net/stevenmchoi/vkgfy1ts/17/

https://codepen.io/stevenmchoi/pen/qJENmj

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
.parent{
  background: linear-gradient( to bottom, transparent 0, blue 100%);
  height: 100vh;
}
.parent .img-container{
   width: 50vw;
   height: 95vh;
}
.parent .img-container img {
  position: fixed;
  right:2%;
  bottom:0px;
  z-index: -1;

}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
      <div class="img-container">
        <img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/swallowed-whole/images/6/60/Monokuma.png/revision/latest?cb=20170312230828" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like the following?

```css
.parent-div {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(white, red);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.monokuma-img {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 50%;
  max-height: 95%;
  right: 2%;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.despair-gradient {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient( to bottom, transparent 75%, #1543E9 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-div">
  <div class="despair-div">
    <img class="monokuma-img" src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/swallowed-whole/images/6/60/Monokuma.png/revision/latest?cb=20170312230828" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="despair-gradient"></div>
</div>
```